# Mod links disappear on profiles with long display names

Tags: bug, profile-page, user-interface, moderator-tools, design

I just noticed that on a profile with a sufficiently long display name, the HTML element containing useful moderator links gets wrapped behind the profile text box and is thus invisible. Best explained by the screenshots:

[image: screenshot with missing links]

versus what it should look like:

[image: screenshot with links present]

I got the latter image by removing part of the name using Firebug.

It's not supposed to do that, is it?

Comment: Ooooh... now I have a way to prevent being whacked by mods! Or, at least, to annoy them as they are trying to whack me. Hmm... maybe not a good idea?

Comment: I've seen this too.  Reducing the font size also fixes it (so you don't have to hack the name), but that's irritating.

Comment: Now let's just create a sock with a long name and inappropriate behavior and watch as the mods strain to get my account removed.

Comment: I've had luck `selecting and dragging down` to force the element to scroll down. This is also a bug on EE.SE

Comment: [This has been reported before](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/long-usernames-cause-issues-with-the-theme), albeit not on MSO

Comment: Does this still happen for you? When I test it (both here, on Physics and on EE.SE), a long username does cause the links to wrap, but they just push the "about me" box down instead of being hidden behind it. Perhaps the CSS has been changed somehow since you reported this?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Yes, I'm seeing the same thing as you do now, so there must have been some change in the CSS.

Comment: OK, voting to close as "not reproducible". Oh, and have a +1. :)

Comment: Oh you can do that? Cool, I'll add my vote as well.