# Inconsistent usage of deleted user name on closed questions

Tags: bug, closed-questions, community-user, post-notices, deleted-accounts

This question is closed: [Mod links disappear on profiles with long display names](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203354/339911)

One of the close voters has been deleted, but his name still exists in the list of voters in the notice message of the post:

> [image: deleted user]

As far as I know user name after deletion should be looks like "user123456". But it's still MichaelT and simultaneously Community in the same notice box.

Seems I never seen Community name without diamond before.

Comment: It simply take the names from two different sources: one is a static "Display Name" column which is set once when the question is closed, and one is "dynamic" user ID column, which is -1 and that is the ID of Community user. Fix would be to update the static column, but it might get complicated.

Comment: @ShadowWizard it is not static. E.g. when [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23959/whats-this-about-labelled-tags) was closed your name was ShaWizDowArd (according to the [chat transcript](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89/2017/8/24)), but it appears as your current name in the close notice box.

Comment: So the logic is bit more complex, maybe there are two columns: UserID and DisplayName in there, and when the UserID contains ID that does not exist any more, it defaults back to the value stored in DisplayName.

Comment: @ShadowWizard developers should know ... and fix! :)